# IPFS versioning - How to get all files from the IPFS key?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, dapp-development, ipfs

Based on the below code, im able to add a file**(`dataobj.txt --QmUUHKjR5ZdrrYmxpXyPrYP3eMyhv9FnRKo1Duv9stzmmw`)** and publish a file and then assign to the key "myIPFSKey".

```
Step 1: ipfs add -r ipfs/dataobj.txt
Step 2: ipfs name publish QmUUHKjR5ZdrrYmxpXyPrYP3eMyhv9FnRKo1Duv9stzmmw
Result: Published to QmVHUPh6TJKZpXjQ4gL2rZU5YYi7Eb3cUsh4xvSfMrZfhU: /ipfs/QmUUHKjR5ZdrrYmxpXyPrYP3eMyhv9FnRKo1Duv9stzmmw
Step 3: ipfs name publish --key=myIPFSKey QmVHUPh6TJKZpXjQ4gL2rZU5YYi7Eb3cUsh4xvSfMrZfhU
http://localhost:8080/ipns/QmVHUPh6TJKZpXjQ4gL2rZU5YYi7Eb3cUsh4xvSfMrZfhU
```

Now i want to update some text on the file(dataobj.txt) and uploaded to the IPFS again. it has returned the new IPFS hash**(`QmfKtQh2apaM9eQM3ohwgfrr3zfSSXd1wsQhMJtvXTurUg`)**. So again i have published the new hash to the IPFS key "myIPFSKey". so far everything goes well.

Here i want to get the list of all the files published to the particular key(myIPFSKey) like versioning. Is it possible to achieve it?

```
Command:   ipfs key list myIPFSKey
Expected O/P:  QmUUHKjR5ZdrrYmxpXyPrYP3eMyhv9FnRKo1Duv9stzmmw dataObj.txt
               QmfKtQh2apaM9eQM3ohwgfrr3zfSSXd1wsQhMJtvXTurUg dataObj.txt
```

Here I'm trying to get both versions of the files from IPFS key(myIPFSKey)

Regards
Mani

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can use IPNS to store more than one CID (hash) but however you can use [IPLD](http://127.0.0.1:8080/ipns/ipld.io/) (IPFS Linked Data) to generate a JSON bundle that will reference each version and only the CID of the bundle will be store on IPNS.

Let's do an example:

**i. Create a file `myfile.txt` containing `first version` and store it on IPFS**

```
$ echo "first version" > myfile.txt 
$ ipfs add myfile.txt 
added QmUCr8K6pNZib5TZ2KAPupdjCqEjpgrm94DJ4UtEQQsuqz myfile.txt
```

**ii. Generate an IPFS bundle referencing this file as version 1**

Basically IPLD allows you to store a JSON object on IPFS where leaves can contain data or links.

```
$ echo '{"version1": {"content": {"/": "QmUCr8K6pNZib5TZ2KAPupdjCqEjpgrm94DJ4UtEQQsuqz"}, "author": "greg"}}' | ipfs dag put
zdpuAqidKVQqA36feYLTLyWV9s4eajMtSmVFJxWpa65o5VFPU
```

Then we can explore the IPLD bundle like this

o Get the entire bundle

```
$ ipfs dag get zdpuAqidKVQqA36feYLTLyWV9s4eajMtSmVFJxWpa65o5VFPU
{"version1":{"author":"greg","content":{"/":"QmUCr8K6pNZib5TZ2KAPupdjCqEjpgrm94DJ4UtEQQsuqz"}}}
```

o Get a specific data within the object

```
$ ipfs dag get zdpuAqidKVQqA36feYLTLyWV9s4eajMtSmVFJxWpa65o5VFPU/version1/author
"greg"
```

o Get a specific content through a link

```
$ ipfs cat zdpuAqidKVQqA36feYLTLyWV9s4eajMtSmVFJxWpa65o5VFPU/version1/content
first version
```

**iii. Store the IPLD hash on IPNS**

This IPLD CID has a content addressable hash `zdpuAqidKVQqA36feYLTLyWV9s4eajMtSmVFJxWpa65o5VFPU` like any other objects on IPFS and can be stored on IPNS

o Generate the key `key`

```
$ ipfs key gen --type=rsa --size=2048 key
QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a
```

o Publish the IPLD CID under this name

```
$ ipfs name publish --key=key zdpuAqidKVQqA36feYLTLyWV9s4eajMtSmVFJxWpa65o5VFPU
Published to QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a: /ipfs/zdpuAqidKVQqA36feYLTLyWV9s4eajMtSmVFJxWpa65o5VFPU
```

o You can then resolve the name and access the version

```
$ ipfs dag get $(ipfs name resolve QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a)/version1/author
"greg"

$ ipfs cat $(ipfs name resolve QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a)/version1/content
first version
```

---

**iv. Let's now create a second version and upload it on IPFS**

```
$ echo "second version" > myfile.txt 
$ ipfs add myfile.txt 
added QmNs9wW2s3fVR3aRJS62Ak8honGdB6PEDjF15FnTWnFeu8 myfile.txt
```

**v. We can recreate a new bundle with the second version**

```
$ echo '{"version1":{"author":"greg","content":{"/":"QmUCr8K6pNZib5TZ2KAPupdjCqEjpgrm94DJ4UtEQQsuqz"}}, "version2":{"author":"mani2020","content":{"/":"QmNs9wW2s3fVR3aRJS62Ak8honGdB6PEDjF15FnTWnFeu8"}}}' | ipfs dag put
zdpuAvKvo6QuvQnwtwYhQrsG82iwgGH4bxZpvKY4hrPuKWxaj
```

And access the data and links

```
$ ipfs dag get zdpuAvKvo6QuvQnwtwYhQrsG82iwgGH4bxZpvKY4hrPuKWxaj/version1/author
"greg"
$ ipfs cat zdpuAvKvo6QuvQnwtwYhQrsG82iwgGH4bxZpvKY4hrPuKWxaj/version1/content
first version
$ ipfs dag get zdpuAvKvo6QuvQnwtwYhQrsG82iwgGH4bxZpvKY4hrPuKWxaj/version2/author
"mani2020"
$ ipfs cat zdpuAvKvo6QuvQnwtwYhQrsG82iwgGH4bxZpvKY4hrPuKWxaj/version2/content
second version
```

**vi. Finally we only need to republish the new hash of the second bundle**

```
$ ipfs name publish --key=key zdpuAvKvo6QuvQnwtwYhQrsG82iwgGH4bxZpvKY4hrPuKWxaj
Published to QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a: /ipfs/zdpuAvKvo6QuvQnwtwYhQrsG82iwgGH4bxZpvKY4hrPuKWxaj

$ ipfs dag get $(ipfs name resolve QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a)/version1/author
"greg"
$ ipfs cat $(ipfs name resolve QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a)/version1/content
first version
$ ipfs dag get $(ipfs name resolve QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a)/version2/author
"mani2020"
$ ipfs cat $(ipfs name resolve QmPU6xFfHykL7HBNbckzB9pCCeVFUx2HD4KxvkQmcYAV6a)/version2/content
second version
```

And so on and so forth !

---

Notes:

- Pinning: If you pin the IPLD Bundle, all linked data will be pinned.

Comment: Glad it worked ! Please don't forget to accept the answer if it fully solve your problem.

Comment: for windows command prompt users:  
**step ii**:   `echo {"version1":{"author":"greg","content":{"/":"QmUCr8K6pNZib5TZ2KAPupdjCqEjpgrm94DJ4UtEQQsuqz"}}} | ipfs dag put`

**step v**:  `echo {"version1":{"author":"greg","content":{"/":"QmUCr8K6pNZib5TZ2KAPupdjCqEjpgrm94DJ4UtEQQsuqz"}}, "version2":{"author":"mani2020","content":{"/":"QmNs9wW2s3fVR3aRJS62Ak8honGdB6PEDjF15FnTWnFeu8"}}} | ipfs dag put`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to IPLD (and somewhat simpler) is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipvfs.